# Rotate between images in loop

Tags: android, android-studio, button, imageview, kotlin

I created a button to switch between two images in loop mode, but I couldn't make it work. 
When I press the button for the second time, the image doesn't change as it should.

Here is my code:

Kotlin:

```
IBRotate.setOnClickListener()
{
    body.setTag(1)

    if(body.getTag() == 1)
    {
        body.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_woman)
        body.setTag(2)
    }
    else if(body.getTag() == 2)
    {
        body.setImageResource(R.drawable.front_woman)
        body.setTag(1)
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/IBRotate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rotate"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/front_woman"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `body.setTag(1)` fron `onclicklistener`
its setting tag to 1 every time button is clicked 
move this line to `onCreate`